# Auth::login("user") in Laravel is not working in event listener

Tags: laravel-5

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::listen('Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent', function (\Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent $event) {

        $user = $event->getSaml2User();
        $laravelUser ===> // retrieving from database
        ///some business logic here
        Auth::login($laravelUser);
        return redirect("homepage");
    }
});
```

It doesn't go to homepage when I trigger and execute this code by firing an event but when I run it like this from a test route it works fine.

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
         $laravelUser ===> // retrieving from database
        ///some business logic here
        Auth::login($laravelUser);
        return redirect("homepage");
    }   
  });
```

Is it because of event listener? why is it behaving as if the user was not authenticated and that's why he got redirected to login page.

Comment: Laravel already has Events if a user logs in. Take a look here -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication For 5.2 take a look here -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

Comment: I know that, I am using SSO and I authenticate user directly if there is a successful SSO operation.

Comment: Looking at the same issue. Any fix?

Comment: @Adsy2010 i remember how i fixed it, it didn't work so i created a function that authenticates the users passed as parameter so after performing login in routes.php I passed the user to that authenticate function it controller and it did the job

Comment: cool! I found this and was about to test it: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/222/manually-logging-a-user-by-id

Comment: this will work fine but the issue is when you use events using triggers

Comment: Its for an internal system via WIA using laravel saml. Its not a major issue really for me. I think ill take the low road for now and look at the proper auth system for a later date using your suggestion, depending if this works or not.